# How to convert table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I had no idea which search keywords to use (that's why the question is vague as well)

I have a table like this

```
Parent_ID     Parent_item    Child_Item
1             A              B
1             A              C
2             H              I
2             H              J
2             H              K
```

And I would like to have the results in the following format:

```
Parent_ID    Parent_or_Child
1            A
1            B
1            C
2            H
2            I
2            J
2            K
```

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpivot the data, and it seems you don't want duplicates so you need to `select distinct`. In Oracle 11.1 or above, you can use the `UNPIVOT` operator - the advantage is that the base table will be read just once.

You can add an `order by` clause if you need it; I didn't, so the rows in the output are in arbitrary order (if you compare to your "desired output").

```
with
     test_data ( Parent_ID, Parent_item, Child_Item ) as (
       select 1, 'A', 'B' from dual union all
       select 1, 'A', 'C' from dual union all
       select 2, 'H', 'I' from dual union all
       select 2, 'H', 'J' from dual union all
       select 2, 'H', 'K' from dual
     )
-- End of test data (NOT part of the query).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select distinct parent_id, parent_or_child
from test_data
unpivot (parent_or_child 
              for col in (parent_item as 'parent_item', child_item as 'child_item'))
;

 PARENT_ID PARENT_OR_CHILD
---------- ---------------
         2 I
         1 A
         1 B
         1 C
         2 H
         2 J
         2 K

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: This is working fine, added an order by to complete it. Thanks!

Comment: @SDR - The result of `UNPIVOT` has a third column, simply named `col` (as defined in the query, in the `unpivot` clause). I don't `select` it, but it is still available, for example, for ordering. If you need to order parents first, and then children, you can have a more complex `order by` clause that achieves that. For example: `order by parent_id, col desc, parent_or_child`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unpivot the data, use `UNION`

```
select Parent_ID,Parent_item
from yourtable
Union 
select Parent_ID,Child_Item
from yourtable
```

Comment: "You need to unpivot the data" is right, so then why use `UNION`? Use `UNPIVOT`! The `UNION` solution reads the base table twice, which may be a significant performance drag.

Comment: @mathguy - Am not sure about the Unpivot syntax in Oracle so didnt post one as answer. But that does not mean this post is not useful